# Using sed for inline substitution of part of matched line

Tags: bash, sed

I have an `.md` file with multiple references to other `.md` files in the form of:

```
[Another file](dir/file.md)
[And another file](dir2/anotherfile.md)
[Yet another file](dir3/yetanotherfile.md)
```

What is the appropriate `sed` command for this inline substitution:

```
[Another file](pdf/dir1/file.pdf)
[And another file](pdf/dir2/anotherfile.pdf)
[Yet another file](pdf/dir3/yetanotherfile.pdf)
```

I know how to capture lines with the specific pattern, e.g. via

```
sed -rn '/\(.+\.md\)/p' README.md
```

but I am unable to operate on the capture group appropriately to perform the transformation.

Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```sh
sed -re 's#\[([^]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\.md\)#[\1](pdf/\2.pdf)#g'
```

This will match on the whole link expression, and replace `*.md` with `pdf/*.pdf`. This will also match links that are *somewhere* in a line - not alone.

If you want to update the file's content, then use the `-i` flag:

```sh
sed -re 's#\[([^]]+)\]\(([^\)]+)\.md\)#[\1](pdf/\2.pdf)#g' -i README.md
```

---

Input:

```
[Another file](dir/file.md)
[And another file](dir/anotherfile.md)
[Yet another file](dir/yetanotherfile.md)
```

Output:

```
[Another file](pdf/dir/file.pdf)
[And another file](pdf/dir/anotherfile.pdf)
[Yet another file](pdf/dir/yetanotherfile.pdf)
```

Answer (score 2):

Edit : you should prefer [Attie's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46889118/1678362) which matches full links. I'll leave my solution which might explain more details.

---

You will want to group the parts you will reproduce in the output in capturing groups, then reference them in the replacement pattern with back references.

Using the `-r` (in GNU sed) or `-E` (in BSD sed or recent GNU sed) flags makes capturing groups more readable since you don't have to escape the brackets.

In your case you want to capture the filename without its extension.

This is the command I would use (where `+` is the delimiter instead of the usual `/` that would conflict with file path separator) :

```
sed -E 's+]\((.*)\.md\)+](pdf/\1.pdf)+g'
```

POC :

```
$ echo "[Another file](dir/file.md)
> [And another file](dir/anotherfile.md)
> [Yet another file](dir/yetanotherfile.md)" | sed -E 's+]\((.*)\.md\)+](pdf/\1.pdf)+g'
[Another file](pdf/dir/file.pdf)
[And another file](pdf/dir/anotherfile.pdf)
[Yet another file](pdf/dir/yetanotherfile.pdf)
```

Comment: `-E` is not a valid option on my system... it appears to be an undocumented BSD compatibilty using flag. `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: @Attie and your `-r` won't work on BSD sed ;) I've improved my answer to mention where each flag is relevant

Comment: Oh, interesting, "_in BSD sed or recent GNU sed_" - thanks.

Comment: @Attie The use of `-E` on recent GNU versions is discutable, but I like it better than `-r` since it is coherent with other tools such as `grep` and is the initial of the `Extended Regular Expression` flavour it makes `sed` switch to

Answer (score 0):

The more robust **awk** solution:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{ $2="(pdf/"substr($2,1,length($2)-2)"pdf)"; $0=$1$2 }1' README.md
```

The output:

```
[Another file](pdf/dir/file.pdf)
[And another file](pdf/dir/anotherfile.pdf)
[Yet another file](pdf/dir/yetanotherfile.pdf)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, really helpful. Why is the `awk` approach more robust if I may ask?

Comment: I doubt it is, it doesn't even match the closing `]` of links definition and will thus mess with literal parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Another with sed whithout -r or -E option

```
sed 's/\([^(]*(\)\([^.]*.\).*/\1pdf\/\2pdf)/' infile
```